# Find time duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have two date fields with times.They are

1.2008-06-09 10:18:00.000

2.2008-06-10 11:20:00.000

I have to find the difference between the above two dates in the format -

"24 hour:2 minutes:0 seconds"

Is there any method to get this result in sql 2000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fancy answer in SQL Server 2000...

```
DECLARE @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime 

SELECT @d1 = '2008-06-09 10:18:00.000', @d2 = '2008-06-10 11:20:00.000'

SELECT
    CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, @d1, @d2) AS varchar(30)) + ' hours, ' +
    CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, @d1, @d2) % 60 AS varchar(30))  + ' minutes, ' +
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @d1, @d2) % 3600 % 60 AS varchar(30))  + ' seconds'
```

The modulos are needed to remove hours and minutes already calculated

Comment: I believe that you need to account for crossing borders when the smaller unit is less in `@d2` then `@d1`. For example, change the minutes in `@d2` to be 15 and check your results.

Comment: These changes should work: `CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @d1, @d2)/3600 AS varchar(30)) + ' hours, ' +
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @d1, @d2)/60 % 60 AS varchar(30))  + ' minutes, ' +
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @d1, @d2) % 3600 % 60 AS varchar(30))  + ' seconds'`